# Install something without make install

Tags: software-installation, python, gcc, make

I have been struggling for few days trying to install a software. I'm not actually working on Ubuntu but I think the steps to do are the same. Working on a gentoo (The operating system of the Robot NAO) distribution with no gcc and no make installed and no easy way to install them by myself. I want to install portaudio and the pyaudio library for python. All I have is a virtual machine emulating the robot where gcc and make are available. ./configure and make work well on the virtual machine. Then I copy the folder with the generated binaries to the robot but can't run make install due to the missing make. I was able to manually install pyaudio by putting the .py in the right location but portaudio (pyaudio depends on it) is more tricky. Now, whenever I try "import pyaudio" I have an error message asking for installing portaudio first. I tried to open the makefile and follow what the install section is doing with no success. I also searched for all files called portaudio after installing portaudio on the virtual machine and copied them one to one to the robot. Still getting an error when importing pyaudio. Does somebody know how to do an install manually?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can usually do this by passing `--prefix=/path/to/empty/folder` to `configure`.  This will put the installed components into your previously-empty folder in the correct structure once you run `make install`.  Then, you can copy all the contents of this folder onto your target system.

Comment: Thanks this helped me realize that somehow pyaudio was looking for the libraries at usr/lib and not usr/local/lib on the robot.